# Couchbase - Case with subquery

Tags: subquery, case, couchbase, sql++

I am going to write a case which has subquery, something like below, But I cannot get neither out put nor error:

```
select
case
when f.resGeo.isRural = true 
  then (select g.ID as geo_id
    from bktsample.scpPC.GeoInfo g 
    where g.PROVINCE_ID = f.resGeo.province.id 
     and g.CITYES_ID = f.resGeo.countie.id
     and g.PART_ID = f.resGeo.part.id
     and g.CITYORCOUNTRY_ID = f.resGeo.countie.id
     and g.VILLAGE_ID = f.resGeo.village.id)
when f.resGeo.isRural = false
  then (select g.ID 
    from bktsample.scpPC.GeoInfo g 
    where g.PROVINCE_ID = f.resGeo.province.id 
     and g.CITYES_ID = f.resGeo.countie.id
     and g.PART_ID = f.resGeo.part.id
     and g.CITYORCOUNTRY_ID = f.resGeo.countie.id) 
end as geo_id

from bktsample.scpPC.Family f;
```

PS: GEO is my collection, scpPC is my scope and bktsample is my bucket.

Comment: I'm confused by "neither out put nor error". Something must be happening when you execute this query. Is it timing out? What indexes have you created?

Comment: I do not get any out put, It is like output:[]

Comment: I see: the query is returning 0 results

Answer (score 1):

Each document in the Family collection should have returned one document of geo_id (either empty array or objects of ID)

Small change to your query:

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON bktsample.scpPC.Family(resGeo.province.id, resGeo.countie.id, resGeo.part.id, resGeo.countie.id, resGeo.village.id, resGeo.isRural);
CREATE INDEX ix2 ON bktsample.scpPC.GeoInfo(PROVINCE_ID, CITYES_ID, PART_ID, CITYORCOUNTRY_ID, VILLAGE_ID, ID);

SELECT
    (SELECT g.ID AS geo_id
     FROM bktsample.scpPC.GeoInfo AS g
     WHERE g.PROVINCE_ID = f.resGeo.province.id
           AND g.CITYES_ID = f.resGeo.countie.id
           AND g.PART_ID = f.resGeo.part.id
           AND g.CITYORCOUNTRY_ID = f.resGeo.countie.id
           AND (f.resGeo.isRural == false OR g.VILLAGE_ID = f.resGeo.village.id))
    ) AS geo_ids
FROM bktsample.scpPC.Family f
WHERE f.resGeo.province.id IS NOT NULL;
```